# Sporadic MySQL connection errors for 5-10 seconds

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I have a small portal website, with 7-8000 visitors/day, I do all the SQL queries and coding.

I find that sometimes the website can't connect to the database - instead for 5-10 seconds it shows the message *'Cannot connect to mysql...'*. This is `mysql_connect error`, after 15 second everything returns to normal for a few hours. No login change, no hosting problems. I put `mysql_close()` on the footer of website, but the issue still occurs.

What could be the cause of this kind of error? Where should I search to find the problems and solve them? Could it be to many connection too the page?

Comment: Just a little clarification: have you been able to retrieve and log the exact error message? Is it a shared hosting account?

Comment: the error message is show on the entire website, if you are a visitor you can see the mesagge: no connection :) and nothing else, I have a include_once to database_conection.php on the top of every page, generally speaking if I change the password on the database_connection.php i have the same error type. I pay for hosting, they told me that is no problem  or limitations, and to try to put mysql_close() on the footer part, but with no result.

Comment: Have you finally found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I can only provide you a few general tips but I hope they help anyway:

- You say you get `cannot connect to mysql...` and nothing else. That sounds like you have some code at "database_conection.php" that explicitly prints such message on connection error.  PHP default errors tend to be more verbose and include error codes, file names, line number...
- Wherever you call [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/mysql_connect) you can enhance error handling quite easily:

  - Test the return value of the function.
  - On error, call [mysql_error()](http://php.net/mysql_error) to obtain the exact error message will all the details.
  - Log all the details you need to identify the piece of code that triggered the error. For instance, [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) can tell you the precise function call chain.
- PHP offers several error handling directives to fine tune what to do on error. Have a look at [display_errors](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), [log_errors](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) and [error_reporting](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).
- I'm not sure about how you expect [mysql_close()](http://php.net/mysql_close) to help but this function requires a working connection and it simply closes it. Furthermore, I suppose your footer is close to the end of the script, where the connection will be closed automatically anyway.
- If you are using a shared hosting account your site will not be the only user of the MySQL server. If it's simply timing-out due to high load it doesn't need to be *your* site's fault necessarily.

Comment: Álvaro G. Vicario thank you, I put  mysql_error and mysql_errno to find what is wrong, searching more about this problem, I find that is possible to have some hack problems, so I change the db password and verify all the files. I waiting to see if the error will appers again. Any new advices are welcome. Tx again.